# When user click on a button the text on button appears in edittext

Tags: button, linker, onclick

I want to create a textfield that holds the user's text only until the user clicks a submit button. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :-) The people who can read your mind are on psychictalent.com and the guys who can see what's on your desktop are at nsa.gov ;-) If you want us to help you, need to tell us exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly you want to do some event(i.e appearing of text) till the user clicks the button(i.e mouse down) **Correct me if I am wrong**

Use the event `onmousedown`

Documentation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp)

[Test it here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmousedown)